# Locating tick marks at integral multiples of pi/2

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Originally in my code, I had

`xtick={-2*pi, -(3/2)*pi, -(1/2)*pi, (1/2)*pi,(3/2)*pi, 2*pi},`

to put tick marks at integral multiples of $pi/2$.  It would not compile.  I had to replace it with cumbersome decimal approximations.  Why won't the code compile with expressions like `pi`?  To specify width of the x-axis in the `axis` environment, I used `xmin=-2*pi,` and `xmax=2*pi,`, and to specify the domain of the cosine function, I used `domain=-2*pi:2*pi`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4.5in,clip=false,
    xmin=-2*pi,xmax=2*pi,
    ymin=-1.25,ymax=1.25,
    axis lines=middle,
    %xtick={-2*pi, -(3/2)*pi, -pi, -(1/2)*pi, (1/2)*pi, pi, (3/2)*pi, 2*pi},
    xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708, 1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318},
    xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white},
    xticklabels={$-2\pi$,,$-\pi$,,,$\pi$,,$2\pi$},
    ytick={-1},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white},
    yticklabels={$-1$},
    extra y ticks={1},
    extra y tick labels={$1$},
    extra y tick style={yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white,anchor=south east}},
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot [samples=501,mark=none, thick, red,domain=-2*pi:2*pi] {cos(deg(x))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the answer but you can reduce the number of calculations by using `xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, ..., 6.28318}`.

Answer (score 9):

With the release of PGFPlots v1.16 it is now possible to use the math parser at
several places. And thus you can use your provided `xtick` line now ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick={-2*pi, -(3/2)*pi, -pi, -(1/2)*pi, (1/2)*pi, pi, (3/2)*pi, 2*pi},
%        xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708, 1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318},
        xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white},
        xticklabels={$-2\pi$,,$-\pi$,,,$\pi$,,$2\pi$},
        ytick={-1,1},
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
        samples=501,
        enlargelimits=true,
    ]
        \addplot [thick,red] {cos(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 5):

The list can be evaluated separately via `\pgfmathparse` or `\pgfmathsetmacro`. The comma list is converted to an array, where the calculated numbers are put into curly braces. Thus the following example defines macro `\ArrayToCommaList` to get a comma separated list again:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ArrayToCommaList}[1]{%
  \let\ArrayToCommaList@Result\@empty
  \expandafter\@tfor\expandafter\ArrayToCommaList@Entry
  \expandafter:\expandafter=#1\do{%
    \edef\ArrayToCommaList@Result{%
      \ArrayToCommaList@Result,\ArrayToCommaList@Entry
    }%
  }%
  % Remove first comma
  \edef#1{%
    \expandafter\@cdr\ArrayToCommaList@Result\@empty\@nil
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xticklist{-2*pi, -(3/2)*pi, -pi, -(1/2)*pi,
  (1/2)*pi, pi, (3/2)*pi, 2*pi}
\ArrayToCommaList\xticklist
\begin{axis}[width=4.5in,clip=false,
    xmin=-2*pi,xmax=2*pi,
    ymin=-1.25,ymax=1.25,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick=\xticklist,
    xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white},
    xticklabels={$-2\pi$,,$-\pi$,,,$\pi$,,$2\pi$},
    minor x tick num=2,
    ytick={-1},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white},
    yticklabels={$-1$},
    extra y ticks={1},
    extra y tick labels={$1$},
    extra y tick style={yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white,anchor=south east}},
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,fill=white},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot [samples=501,mark=none, thick, red,domain=-2*pi:2*pi] {cos(deg(x))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Forget the list.  Suppose that I wanted to make a tick mark at $\pi/2$.  Why can't I have something like `xtick={(1/2)*pi},` in my code?

Comment: @Adelyn `xtick` expects a plain floating point number, calculations are not supported. Make a feature request.

Comment: Please tell me the procedure to make a feature request.

Comment: @Adelyn Go to http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/ and submit your request.  You might need an account on Sourceforge though.

Comment: I am the author of pgfplots and I accept this as feature request. The reason for the missing math parser support is merely legacy: back in the past, there was no math parser with the required precision. In the meantime, it was either accepted or forgotten. I'll revise the math parsing of input arguments as feature request; this will affect other keys as well.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger --- I was looking at the feature list and see no mention of this... has been already added?  Thanks!

Comment: @ Rmano the pgfplotstodo.tex in text form contained as associated item. I have converted it into a sourceforge feature request: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/69/

Answer (score 3):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pst-plot}    
\begin{document}

\psset{yunit=3}
\begin{pspicture}(-6.75,-1.3)(6.75,1.3)
\psframe*[linecolor=yellow!80!black!20](-6.7,-1.3)(6.7,1.3)
\psaxes[trigLabels,dx=3.14]{<->}(0,0)(-6.6,-1.25)(6.6,1.25)
\psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,
        linecolor=red,plotpoints=1000]{-6.28}{6.28}{cos(x)}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with ticks every pi/2:

```
\psaxes[trigLabels,trigLabelBase=2,dx=1.57]{<->}(0,0)(-6.6,-1.25)(6.6,1.25)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-4.3,0.) -- (5.1,0.);
\draw[shift={(-3.14,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $-\pi$};
\draw[shift={(-1.6,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $-\pi/2$};
\draw[shift={(1.6,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\pi/2$};
\draw[shift={(3.14,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\pi$};
\draw[shift={(4.7,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $3\pi/2$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0.,-2.11) -- (0.,1.33);
\foreach \y in {-2.,-1.,1.}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (.5pt,0pt) -- (-.5pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\draw[line width=2.pt,color=magenta,smooth,samples=500,domain=-5:5] plot(\x,{cos(((\x))*180/pi)});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=magenta] (-4.6,.5) node {$f(x)=\cos x$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```